# Save Excel Workbook in the current directory using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a simple vbscript that I want to demo, and it will optimally create an excel workbook in whatever directory the script is run from. Here is what I have so far.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
Sheet = 1
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet)

objSheet.Name = "EXAMPLE"


strExcelPath = "C:\Users\EXAMPLE\EXAMPLE.xlsx"

(data values)

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strExcelPath
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objSheet = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Done."
```

I can't quite figure out how to work the CurDir function into the SaveAs. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code appropriately to get current directory using VBScript.

```
dim fso
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

dim CurrentDirectory
CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

strExcelPath = fso.BuildPath(CurrentDirectory, "Example.xlsx")
```

or you could also use CurrentDirectory property of WScript shell in VBScript.

```
Dim WshShell, strCurDir
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCurDir    = WshShell.CurrentDirectory
strExcelPath = strCurDir & "\Example.xlsx"
```